# Sequence of bounded variation functions that converge uniformly to a function with unbounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, bounded-variation

I need help with this exercise:
Prove that $\exists (f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset BV([0,1])$ such that $f_{n}\to f$ uniformly, but $\|f_{n}-f\|_{BV}\not\to 0$.

So I proposed the sequence $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where:$$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\quad x=0\\
x^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) &\quad x\in(0,1]
\end{cases}$$I proved that $\|f_{n}\|_{BV}=|f_{n}(0)|+V_{0}^{1}(f_{n})=V_{0}^{1}(f_{n})<\infty$ and that $f_{n}\to f$ uniformly where $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\quad x=0\\
x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) &\quad x\in(0,1]
\end{cases}$$ and such that $\|f\|_{BV}=|f(0)|+V_{0}^{1}(f)=V_{0}^{1}(f)$ is not finite.

I'm having trouble proving that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{BV}\not\to 0$. I know that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{BV}=|(f_{n}-f)(0)|+V_{0}^{1}(f_{n}-f)=V_{0}^{1}(f_{n}-f)\leq V_{0}^{1}(f_{n})+V_{0}^{1}(f)$ but this doesn't imply the norm is not zero.
I also thought I could use the fact that $\|g\|_{BV}=0 \iff g\equiv0$, but I'm stucked.

Comment: don't you have $V_0^1 (f) = \infty $ ?

Comment: Actually, you solved everything. To finish, use $||a-b||\geq |\|a-\|b\| |$.